# Преобразование в ссылку

Tags: php

Как преобразовать `$tpl->sub_load_template('sub.tpl'));` в ссылку типа `index.php?do=sub`

Ну вот смотрите: `http://makar3000.s3.webhost1.ru/panel2/index.php?do=login`

Появляется `main.tpl` и новый шаблон. В `index.php`

```
include ("templates.class.php");

$do = $_GET['do'];
if ($do == 'login') {
    include './templates/login.tpl';
}

$tpl   = new Template; //инициируем класс
$tpl->dir = 'templates/'; //задаём местоположение папки с шаблонами
$tpl->load_template('main.tpl'); //загружаем каркас

$tpl->compile('main'); //собираем шаблон
echo $tpl->result['main']; //выводим результат работы
$tpl->global_clear(); //очищаем все переменные для возможно следующего шаблона
```

А мне нужно, что бы при переходе на `index.php?do=login` показывало только `login.tpl`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть гвозди, молоток и доски, как построить вот такое ... ?

Смотрите в сторону глобальной переменной $_GET. Коротко можно сказать, чтобы что-то конкретное получить по index.php?do=sub

В файле index.php

```
if (!empty($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == "sub") {
//контент или подключение другово файла, который например загрузит вам шаблон
} else {

}
```

Comment: Нет, пробывал... Он добавляет еще один шаблон к main.tpl а мне нужно что бы вместо main ставился login или другие

Answer (score 1):

Пока не поймёте работу суперглобального массива $_GET, дальше лучше и не суйтесь.
Пример :

```
<?php
$var1   =   $_GET['keyname'];
#
if ($var1 == 'home') {
    echo 'Это домашняя страница';
} elseif ($var1 == 'about') {
    echo 'А это страница about';
}
?>
```

Посмотрите внимательно на код, и представьте, что `$_GET[]` - это массив, keyname в массиве `$_GET` - ключ массива, чтобы этот ключ содержал данные, мы должны их ему присвоить, но немного другим способом, вот так (открыть в браузере на сайте) : `имя_этого_скрипта.php?keyname=123`.
И при такой записи, переменная `$var1` в нашем скрипте будет равна "123".
Пары ключ/значение в URL перечисляются через символы & (and), пример :
`zxzx.php?kluch1=znachenie1&key2=value123123`
Из записи выше мы узнаем, что `$_GET['kluch1']` равна znachenie1, а `$_GET['key2']` соответственно value123123.

Comment: вопрос на засыпку сколько максимум вложеных условий поддерживает конструкция с if'ом ?)

юзай свитч

Comment: а чёрт его знает, мне 10-и или 15-и хватает, темболее не одно условие обычно использую, 3-4, поэтому иф)

Answer (score 1):

эм.... я в DLE мало капошился..но по мойму тут и нубу понятно, как надо сделать:

```
include ("templates.class.php");

$tpl   = new Template; //инициируем класс
$tpl->dir = 'templates/'; //задаём местоположение папки с шаблонами
switch($_GET['do'])
{
     case 'login':
         $tpl->load_template('login.tpl'); //загружаем каркас
    break;
    default:
          $tpl->load_template('main.tpl'); //загружаем каркас
}
$tpl->compile('main'); //собираем шаблон
echo $tpl->result['main']; //выводим результат работы
$tpl->global_clear(); //очищаем все переменные для возможно следующего шаблона
```