# PHP и ссылки

Tags: php

Имеется 4 файла: index.php (основной), form_login.php (форма с проверкой логина и пароля), reg.php (новая страница, в которой идет подключение файла registr.php), registr.php (форма регистрации с проверкой параметров). Скажите, пожалуйста, как все эти файлы слить воедино? Например, как обработать ссылку, чтоб при нажатии на оную загружалась в том же окне форма регистрации? Вот код ссылки

```
<FORM  method="POST" target="_self">
 </A></A>Логин:<INPUT type="text" name="log">Пароль:<INPUT type="password" name="par"><INPUT type="submit" name="vhod" value="Войти">
<A href="registr.php"><FONT size="2">Регистрация</FONT></A>
</FORM>
```

Ведь чтоб подгрузить форму необходимо выгрузить информацию, которая была до нее. Как это сделать средствами PHP, не применяя AJAX?

Comment: Ниче не понял. Разве в вашем коде форма регистрации открывается в другом окне? И что значит слить воедино? И при чем тут код ссылки, когда у вас код формы написан? Попробуйте задачу переформулировать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да форма регистрации открывается в новом окне. Взята за каркас основная страница - скопирована в новый файл и в него подгружается файл с формой регистрации. Слить воедино - затем что бы был один большой файл INDEX а не куча разрозненных файлов. Ссылка здесь приведена затем что бы показать как при нажатии на эту ссылку находящуюся в индексе в индексе же появлялась форма регистрации(типа онклика, только в пхп). Но чтоб она появилась - нужно сначала убрать уже имеющуюся инфу со страницы, и только потом показывать форму. Вот в этом и трудность....

Answer (score 1):

Так вам нужен аякс (асинхронная загрузка части содержимого страницы), потому что вы именно его и описали))

А вообще может, вам шаблоны подойдут.

```
<!-- верхняя часть сайта -->
<?
$task = (!empty($_GET['task'])) ? $_GET['task'] : false;
if ($task == 'reg') {
  require 'registr.php'; // показываем форму регистрации
  } else if ($task == 'login') {
  require 'form_login.php'; // показываем форму авторизации
  } else {
  // другие действия
  }
?>
<!-- нижняя часть сайта -->
```

тогда ссылки будут соответственно

```
<a href="index.php?task=reg">Регистрация</a>
<a href="index.php?task=login">Авторизация</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [link text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18868/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/18973)
Я уже отвечал в другом вопросе.